# Xamarin Forms Webview EvaluateJavaScriptAsync error on IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms-4

I work with an application made in Xamarin Forms that works on Android and IOS. I use a webview with a html and inside this html I call a javascript function when I login.

On Android it works fine but on IOS it doesn't work.

I read and apparently the error is due to the change from UIWebview to WKWebview, but so far I don't know how to fix this error.

I made my application on Windows in Visual Studio 2019, on the simulator device it works but on a physical device it doesn't work. In this case on Iphone not works.

This is my code:

LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyLogin.Views.LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
           
            <Label Text="Sign In" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Title" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="50" />
            <Entry x:Name="emailEntry"
            Grid.Row="2"
            BackgroundColor="#31FFFFFF"           
            Placeholder="Email"
            PlaceholderColor="#3AAAF4" />
            <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Margin="0,0,0,0"
            BackgroundColor="#31FFFFFF"
            IsPassword="True"
            Placeholder="Password"
            PlaceholderColor="#3AAAF4" />
            <Button Text="Login" Clicked="OnLoginButtonClicked" BackgroundColor="#3AAAF4" TextColor="White" CornerRadius="8"  />
            <Label></Label>
            <Label x:Name="messageLabel" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="50" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
            <WebView x:Name="webView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="false" />
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

LoginPage.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Plugin.DeviceInfo;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.Web;

namespace MyLogin.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string BlackboxString = "";

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webView.Source = LoadHTMLFileFromResource();
        }
             
        async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         
            var blackbox = "";
           
            blackbox = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync($"getBlackbox()");          


            //Code to login
        }

  
      
        private string GetLocalAddress()
        {
            var IpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault();

            if (IpAddress != null)
                return IpAddress.ToString();

            return "Could not locate IP Address";
        }

        HtmlWebViewSource LoadHTMLFileFromResource()
        {
            var source = new HtmlWebViewSource();

            // load HTML embed in PCL
            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("mypage.mypagename.html");
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                source.Html = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me,

Thanks

Comment: are you actually getting an error, or does it just not work?

Comment: It just not work, I made my application on Windows in Visual Studio 2019, on the simulator device it works but on a physical device it doesn't work. In this case on Iphone not work

Comment: please post the result of your html file `mypage.mypagename.html` so we could have a look. And is there any error?

Comment: The problem is not the html. I test my app without the EvaluateJavascript and works but I don't receive my token. The reason to develop this program of this form is that I had to integrate one third-party software because this is one of the requirements of this project.

Comment: This third-party software has been developed years ago and previously worked with UIWebview and EvaluateJavaScriptAsync without problems, however when the change was made to WKWebview it stopped working. What I need is pass the token that I obtain in the javascript to the code of my application and when doing identify it and login my app, but since this token is obtained by opening the webview, I do not know how made to identify which device has obtained the javascript in the webview if several devices connect simultaneously.

Comment: So you should update the  third-party software to make it work with WKWebview ?